# What does it mean by length of palandrome in theory of automata? even palindrome? odd palindrome?

Tags: automata-theory

Palindrome is a language in automata. But i am unable to understand the following paragraph. I have calculated many things, and tried my best to estimate, but i couldnot.

Length of palindroma:
As we know that string is of length n and numbfer of symbols in the alphabet is 2, which shows that there are as many palindromes of length 2n as there are the strings of lenth n i.e. the required number of palindromes are 2^n.

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome is a word that is the same read from the left as read from the right. So the first half determines completely the letters in the second half. This is why the number of palindromes of length $2n$ is equal to the number of words of length $n$ - the latter are all the possible first halfs of words of length $2n$.

Over an alphabet of two letters you have two choices for each of the $n$ positions, so there are $2^n$ distinct words of length $n$.